# GraphQL Queries in an Apollo app trigger hundreds of duplicate requests

Tags: reactjs, heroku, graphql, next.js, apollo

I have a React app using Next.js and Apollo, and after deploying it to Heroku, I’m encountering problems where the app hangs up and crashes. I’ve figured out that GraphQL queries (but not mutations) are responsible: when a query fires, I can see Heroku’s logs that the server side of the app gets flooded with hundreds of seemingly redundant POST requests (an example request is shown below).  When multiple queries fire at once, the flood of activity can crash the app.

What can I do to fix this?

Here is more information that will hopefully be revealing:

- The queries successfully receive data from the GraphQL server.
- Mutations and local-state queries in Apollo do not cause the same
  flood; they work normally.
- In the browser, the “Network” tab in dev tools shows no POST requests
  happening to the front-end domain; only the usual GET requests (and
  the requests to the GraphQL server domain)
- I don’t detect the same issue in local development.
- The requests look like this:

  ```
   2020-04-20T05:04:21.861390+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=recipe-market.herokuapp.com request_id=7ac33b80-59cc-4893-a8c0-5224dd2906b9 fwd="(My IP address here),18.205.161.72" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=79ms status=200 bytes=1151 protocol=https
  ```
- … and each subsequent request in the flood is identical including the request ID, except the second address in the `fwd` field gets duplicated, e.g.: `fwd="(My IP address here), 18.205.161.72,18.205.161.72"`
  … and it repeats until there are about 300 duplicates of that second address in the `fwd` field
- the flood of requests does not seem to be infinite; it stops at about 300.  All the queries I have tested trigger the same number of requests.

Comment: I put a band-aid on this problem by using a custom server for Next.js to handle POST requests with a status 405 response, which stopped the floods.  In the process, I learned that the POST requests WERE GraphQL queries; I still don't know why the server-side of the front-end app was receiving them.